# How can I configure SOLR 9 with the contrib dataimport handler so that last index time is written to the dataimport.properties file

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have a working configuration of dataimporthandler with SOLR 9 and have run a full import. However, after the full import logged the message that it has completed successfully I got a No Node message re the dataimport.properties file:

o.a.s.h.d.ZKPropertiesWriter Could not read DIH properties from /configs/codes/dataimport.properties :class org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException => org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /configs/codes/dataimport.properties

I thought the full import created the dataimport.properties file. I tried creating an empty file with open write permission, and posting it to the configset with zookeeper putfile. I confirmed that the file was present in the config, but the full dataimport does not seem to update it with "last index time" as I'm used to seeing with earlier versions of SOLR and dataimporthandler.